# Gabor Phase ?? my values are too small

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler, time-frequency

Hi every one >> hope you all are doing fine

I wanted to ask you about calculating the phase values for an image ,, you see I used the Gabor wavlet like so :

```
k = ( Kmax / ( f ^ v ) ) * exp( 1i * u * pi / 8 );% Wave Vector

kn2 = ( abs( k ) ) ^ 2;

GW = zeros ( R , C );

for m = -R/2 + 1 : R/2

       for n = -C/2 + 1 : C/2 

        GW(m+R/2,n+C/2) = ( kn2 / Delt2 ) * exp( -0.5 * kn2 * ( m ^ 2 + n ^ 2 ) / Delt2) * ( exp( 1i * ( real( k ) * m + imag ( k ) * n ) ) - exp ( -0.5 * Delt2 ) );

    end
end
I=imread('a.pgm');

Myimage=conv2(I,double(GW),'same');
```

then I called the image and the filter with different orientations and scales and stored the phase in P then I wanted to quantize it with rang 4 i:

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;

% Parameter Setting

R = 32;
C = 32;
Kmax = pi;
f = sqrt( 2 );
Delt = 2 * pi;
Delt2 = Delt * Delt;

% Show the Gabor Wavelets

for v=1:7 %v = 1 : 7
    for u = 1:5 % u= 1: 5

        [GW,Myimage]= GaborWavelet ( R, C, Kmax, f, u, v, Delt2 ); % Create the Gabor wavelets
       figure;
        subplot( 5, 8, v * 7 + u ),imshow ( real( GW ) ,[]); % Show the real part of Gabor wavelets

    end
   figure ;
    subplot( 1, 5, v + 1 ),imshow ( abs( GW ),[]); % Show the magnitude of Gabor wavelets
end


%clear I;
R=real(GW);

I=imag(GW);

M=abs(Myimage);

P=atan(imag(Myimage)/real(Myimage)); <<<< is this even right ??


%P=atan(I/R);

save P P;

[xx,yy] = size (P);

DATA =zeros(size(P));

for i=1:48
    for j=1:48
        for zz=1:3
           if (360* zz/4) <= abs(P(i,j))&& abs(P(i,j))<(360*(zz+1)/4) 
                 DATA(i,j)=zz ; end;


        end;
    end;
end;
save DATA DATA ;
```

But the data is so small like : -1.49279186693682   1.50990968797986    -1.39225915272978 0.966151874072431

which leads to quantized value of 0 >> Where did I go wrong

Comment: I think you will need to add some more explanation before the regular matlab users can help you with this.
For example: Untill what point does the program do what you expect? And when it does not behave as expected, what does it do and what did you expect exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I think values seem small because they are given in radians and you expect them in degrees. As for getting the magnitude and angle of a complex number, take a look at http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/angle.html.

I quote:

"For complex Z, the magnitude R and phase angle theta are given by

R = abs(Z)

theta = angle(Z)"

**Z** would be your **GW**.

Hope this helps!